# iOS Push UIViewController on slide gesture like Snapchat

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, snapchat

I have a question about iOS push navigation controllers. I want to push view controller on slide gesture. Just like as in Snapchat application: main view captures images. If you slide from left to right, snapchat messages view smoothly slides (pushes) to main window. If you slide from right to left > contacts view. How to create this kind of navigation? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you looked into NavigationViewControllers?  They use a similar animation when animating new viewControllers using the presentViewController method.

Comment: Is it a third party library?

Comment: No! You can make a UINavigationController and use its methods without having to import any additional frameworks. :)

Comment: Oh! UINavigationController! :D. Yes, I believe, that I should use UINavigationController. But how to navigate between navigation controllers on swipe gesture?

Comment: Oh sorry!  Well, to navigate using a swipe, you'll first need to add a swipeGestureRecognizer to the view on the UiNavigationController.  I 'believe' (I could be wrong), but when you recognize a left/right swipe, you can call on the left or right navigationItem methods and present your desired viewController.

Comment: Hmmm... I haven't found that way yet... Can you post example piece of code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the way that Snapchat does it is through UIViewController containment.  Essentially, the main view controller contains a scroll view (paging enabled) with 3 child view controllers (snaps, camera, and contacts).  They don't use a navigation controller to present and pop view controllers as you swipe.

See the documentation on view controller containment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: But snaps and contacts has navigation bar and back button. And, actually acts as like as pushed UIViewControllers...

Comment: The back buttons just alter the `contentOffset` of the scroll view.  They don't actually move you anywhere in the navigation stack.

Comment: Why is it better way than to create swipe based navigation controller?

Comment: The nature of their application would not be appropriate for a navigation controller.  When you leave friends, you aren't done with the view since you could go back to it at another time.  You just navigate away from it.  Therefore a pop is inappropriate.  Not to mention altering a navigation controller to do what you suggest would be very, very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the snapchat application you probably don't want to do this all in one `UINavigationController`.

Here is what you need.

1. `UIViewController` - This will be your main view. In terms of the snapchat application this is where you would take picutre.
2. `UINavigationController` - For the friends list
3. `UINavigationController` - For the snapchat (the green window)

You need to setup two segues, both leading from your main controller. Once you have your segues setup I would suggest writing your own transition. Have a look at `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning`, `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`, `UIviewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.

I am at work, but when I get home I'll throw an example together. However, the above should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: As far as I thought at first, I thought that there is: SnapchatCameraViewController, SnapchatSnapsViewController, SnapchatContactsViewController. SnapchatCameraViewController < swipe < SnapchatSnapsViewController AND SnapchatCameraViewController > swipe > SnapchatContactsViewController